# R - create column based on words in another column

Tags: r

Is there a way to create a new column in an R dataframe based on words in another column?

Such as I have a "color" column with "Blue 1", "Blue 2", up to "Blue 6", and then I have 6 other colors with their own set of numbers after.  Is there a way to create a new column that would just say "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", etc without writing out each color out itself?

```
color2 <- ifelse(color=="Blue 1", "Blue",
    ifelse(color=="Blue 2", "Blue",
    ifelse(color=="Blue 3", "Blue",
    ifelse(color=="Blue 4", "Blue",
    ifelse(color=="Blue 5", "Blue",
    ifelse(color=="Blue 6", "Blue",
                    NA  ))))
```

Obviously, I would continue with the other colors, but is there a more streamlined way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can remove the digits followed by the space by creating a `pattern` in the `sub` and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub("\\s+\\d+", "", color)
```

---

Or with `str_extract`, only extract one or more letters from the start (`^`) of the string

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(color, "^[A-Za-z]+")
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!